# How do you obtain the DOM position of a nested element among identical sibling elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

How do I obtain the exact DOM path to the third list item relative to the document in the example below?

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

How can this be done without there being anything unique in or about the list item in question that would distinguish it from the others, apart from its position among the others (being third). Moreover, this needs to be dynamically obtained on a click event, so it could otherwise be the second list item, or fourth, etc.

What are my options? Thanks ahead for your help.

Comment: Use parent() function until you reach the document element

Answer (score 2):

you can use `eq()`:

```
   var $elem = $('ul:eq(0)').find('li:eq(2)');
```

---

you can use `index()` method:

```
   $elem.click(function(){
      var ind = $(this).index();
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5XH2/

Comment: I understand how to select a specific element (eq/nth-child/...), but how do you dynamically retrieve the specific position in the DOM (relative to the document) of the li that is clicked (disregard the example of the "third")?

Comment: @Charles `.index()` is the method you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This jquery retrieves the 3rd LI:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(3)')
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/VnRjq/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.index()` to retrieve the index of the element clicked.

See a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/Hxwkp/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body ul li:eq(2)").bind("click",function(){
    //
});
```